# Application Page 404 - Upgrade from 2007 to 2010

Tags: publishing-site, upgrade, application-pages

In a 2007 Publishing site developed for a client I deployed some custom pages to URL /CustomPages/Programmes.aspx (rather than application pages going in _Layout).
The site custom master page was used and everything was fine.

Used VSEWss 1.2 and have now upgraded to full SP2010 solution.

I have successfully made the upgrade to 2010 on a development server however when rolling out to client I am seeing a 404 when any of the pages in this custom URL are accessed (normal site pages are fine).

I can see the feature folder there. 
The two differences I can see are:

1. Since moving my project to 2010 the feature folders are prepended
   with assembly name e.g. 14/Features/CustomPages/CustomPages is now
   14/Features/UCOL_CustomPages/CustomPages
2. I have been told security has been set up a lot tighter on the new
   installation compared to the 2007 server

Can anyone suggest why I am getting the 404 or what I can do to resolve this?

Thanks